# Remove duplicate dict based on key and value in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, duplicates

I have a structure data:

```
matches = [
                {
                    "15477084": [1]
                },
                {
                    "360418": [2]
                },
                {
                    "15477084": [1]
                },
                {
                    "15477084": [3,4]
                }
            ]
```

I want to check if the key and value in the key are duplicates, I will remove it. If key and value have many different values I  will combine it.

I hope my result like:

```
matches = [
                {
                    "15477084": [1,3,4]
                },
                {
                    "360418": [2]
                }
            ]
```

This is my code:

```
new_matches = []

for j in matches:
    newdict = dict()
    for key,value in j.items():
        if key in newdict.keys():
            if value not in newdict[key]:
                newdict[key].append(value)
                new_matches.append(newdict)
        else:
            newdict[key] = value
            new_matches.append(newdict)
```

But my result is wrong (my result same with data matches begin). I don't why my result is wrong.

Comment: Why does `15477084` have `[1,2,3]` instead of `[1,1,3,4]`? For your code, you are making empty dict `newdict` in every iteration, so `if key in newdict.keys()` will always be `False`, and thereby not differing from the original input.

Comment: @Chris I have tried `newdict` position outside loop `for j in matches` but it's not working. I want to remove value duplicates based on key so `15477084` need have `[1,3,4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for item in matches:
    for k, v in item.items():
        result[k] += v

print([{k: v} for k, v in result.items()])
```

Output:

```
[{'15477084': [1, 1, 3, 4]}, {'360418': [2]}]
```

EDIT: To make the final output unique:

```
print([{k: list(set(v))} for k, v in result.items()])
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I want to `15477084` had values `[1,3,4]` I want to remove duplicate

Comment: You can modify the final output liked this `print([{k: list(set(v))} for k, v in result.items()])` or use a `set` in the `defaultdict` as others did.

Comment: Can you explain to me why you add `{k: list(set(v))}`, data will remove duplicate? I'm a newbie with comprehension python. Sorry if my question make you annoying

Comment: The `set()` function converts your data into a set which will only contain unique items (you are correct, no duplicates) and the `list()` function will convert it back to a list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

res = defaultdict(list)

for x in matches:
    (k,) = x
    if x[k] not in res[k]:
        res[k].append(x[k])

res = {k: list(chain(*v)) for k, v in res.items()}
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'15477084': [1, 3, 4], '360418': [2]}
```

Comment: thank you so much, but in `res = {k: list(chain(*v)) for k,v in res.items()} I don't understand why you do that. Can you explain it for me

Comment: values in `res` dict is list of lists I am making a flat lsit from that

Comment: Might be better to do `chain.from_iterable(v)` instead of `chain(*v)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because I like pandas I provide a special way to solve your problem. May be you will like it.

```
import json
import pandas as pd


if __name__ == "__main__":
    matches = [
        {"15477084": [1]},
        {"360418": [2]},
        {"15477084": [1]},
        {"15477084": [3, 4]},
    ]
    matches_df = pd.DataFrame(matches)
    matches_df = matches_df.fillna("[]").transpose().astype(str).apply(
        lambda x: list(
            set([record for sub in x.tolist() for record in json.loads(sub)])
        ),
        axis=1,
    )
    result = matches_df.to_dict()
    print(result)
```

This is the result

```
{'15477084': [1, 3, 4], '360418': [2]}
```

Comment: This is the new solution to solve my problems, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

v = defaultdict(set)

for dict_values in matches:
    for key, value in sorted(dict_values.items()):
        print(key)
        for i in value:
            v[key].add(i)
```

output:

```
defaultdict(set, {'15477084': {1, 3, 4}, '360418': {2}})
```

Answer (score 0):

defaultdict can help here

```
from collections import defaultdict

res_matches = defaultdict(list)
for i in matches:
    key, value = list(i.keys())[0], list(i.values())[0]
    to_add = set(value).difference(set(res_matches[key]))
    if to_add:
        res_matches[key].extend(to_add)
print(dict(res_matches))
```

Output

```
{'15477084': [1, 3, 4], '360418': [2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your program is that newdict will be created for every iteration and it will not have any key-value pairs, so the statement (if key in newdict.keys()) always will be false, so else statement will be executed and it will append the dictionary in matches list into new_matches.

And also the statement (if value not in newdict[key]), here value is a list and newdict[key] will also be a list(if you solved the above mentioned problem), so you're comparing two lists. i.e) [1] == [3,4] which will not be true. Instead, you should iterate every value in any one of the list and compare it with another list.

I have provided the solution, by solving the two problems in your program.

```html
matches = [
                {
                    "15477084": [1]
                },
                {
                    "360418": [2]
                },
                {
                    "15477084": [1]
                },
                {
                    "15477084": [3,4]
                }
            ]
            
            
new_matches = []

for j in matches:
    newdict = dict()
    for key,value in j.items():
        if len(new_matches) != 0:
            for k in new_matches:
                if key in k.keys():
                    for i in value:
                        if i not in k[key]:
                            k[key].append(i)
                    break

                else:
                    newdict[key] = value
                    new_matches.append(newdict)                 
        else:
            newdict[key] = value
            new_matches.append(newdict)

print(new_matches)
```